# P = set of polynomials. R is a set of equivalence classes of P, $F:R\rightarrow P$ is defined as $F([f])=df/dx$. Is F a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let P be a set of polynomials with coefficients$\in R$. R is a set of equivalence classes of P. Let $F:R\rightarrow P$ be a derivative operator defined as $F([f])=df/dx$. Is F well defined? Surjective? Injective?

I really have no idea how to interpret this question.

I'd assume it's not injective, because it's an equivalence class so there's some sort of equivalence between them so there's a chance their derivative can be mapped to the same polynomial(This is a stretch, but maybe?).

Surjective seems unlikely cause I doubt every polynomial is mapped to a poly in R especially since P contains R and there's probably a polynomial in R that once you get the derivative doesn't get mapped in P. For example if R is 2x then 2x in P doesn't get mapped to anything because $2xdx=2$

Comment: "set of equivalence classes of P" is not clear. How is the equivalence relation on P defined ?

Comment: For the sake of an example, take an arbitrary equivalence relation. Like "Have the same value at $x = 3$", and let $R$ be the set of all equivalence classes. Then is $F$ well-defined? Do you know what they mean when they ask about well-defined-ness?

Comment: whether it's a function yes?

Comment: Yup. And when you take what is clearly a well-defined function $P\to P$ (differentiation), and then you try reshape it into a function $R\to P$, there is a single particular thing that can go wrong. Do you know what that is?

Comment: I can think of a few things, R is definitely smaller than P, because it's a subset of P and it's very unlikely very element in P gets mapped to an R since a derivative only changes one function to one other? Is that what you were aiming at?

Comment: @user8714896 Not at all. Restricting a function to a smaller domain doesn't make it not a function, it is a completely unproblematic operation that is done all the time. However, what $R$ does that might make $F$ not a function is that it lumps functions together. Thus the same equivalence class (i.e. the same element of $R$) might give different function values depending on which representative you choose. _This_ is what might make $F$ not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For F to be a function it is necessary that equivalent functions have the same derivative.
In that case F is subjective by taking the integral.
It is not injective.
The set of polynomials with rational constant terms and the set of polynomials irrational constant terms is sufficient example of equivalence classes mapping to the same polynomial.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little fuzzy on how if F is a function that equivalent functions have the same derivative? And how that leads to F being surjective.